# остановить отправку формы ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Как при соответствующем ответе от пхп файла остановить отправку формы.Сейчас форма отправляется в любом случае.

js

```
 (function(){    
xml = eventsObj.getXmlHttp();    

         if(document.getElementById('hidden_change_password_table')){          

            changePassword = function(){
            var newPwd = document.getElementById('new_password').value,
                repeatPwd = document.getElementById('new_password_repeat').value;
                password = document.getElementById('old_password').value;
            if(password === "" || repeatPwd === "" || newPwd === "" || (password != repeatPwd)){
                document.getElementById('new_error').innerHTML = "new pwd != repeat pwd/ empty field";                               
            }
            else{
                xml.open("POST","../model/ajax/change_password.php",true);
                xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xml.send("password="+encodeURIComponent(password));
                xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xml.readyState === 4){
                        if(xml.status === 200){
                            if(xml.responseText !== ""){

                                if(xml.responseText === "ok"){
                                    alert("old pwd == db pwd");                                    
                                }
                                else if(xml.responseText === "error"){
                                    document.getElementById('old_error').innerHTML = "old pwd != db pwd";

                                }   

                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
    };
            eventsObj.addEvent(document.getElementById('change_pwd_form'), 'submit', changePassword, false);

        }
    })();
```

php

```
// $result[2]["password"] - пароль из бд
    if ( $_POST['old_password'] == $result[2]["password"] ){
        echo "ok";
    } else  {
        echo "error";
    }
```

Comment: Перенести эту `eventsObj.addEvent(document.getElementById('button_save'), 'submit', changePassword, false); ` строку в соответствующий ответ сервера

Comment: так она ж вызывает ф-ю ajax сразу после закрывающей скобки той же ф-и

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерно так, можно реализировать всё это.
Данные для переменной `tmp_pass` можно получать по-другому через `json`, или проверкой уже на бэкенде.

Если нужно больше деталей - то пишите на почту romanko95.rk@gmail.com.
И после нахождения ответа - мы поделимся им с другими.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tmp_pass = "ooiusger7c34to7y"
  var type = 1;

  $('form input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    $('form input[type="button"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    var formData = $('form').serialize();

    switch (type) {
      case 1:
        if (tmp_pass != $('input[name="cPass"]').val()) {
          $('div#result').removeClass('success').addClass('failed').text('Wrong current password').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);

        } else {

          if ($('input[name="pass1"]').val() == $('input[name="pass2"]').val()) {
            $('div#result').removeClass('failed').addClass('success').text('Password changed to ' + $('input[name="pass1"]').val()).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            tmp_pass = $('input[name="pass1"]').val();
          } else {
            $('div#result').removeClass('success').addClass('failed').text('Wrong passwords for changing').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
          }

        }
        break;
      case 2:

        if ($('input[name="pass1"]').val() == $('input[name="pass2"]').val()) {

          $.post('change_password.php', formData, function(resp) {
            resp = JSON.parse(resp);

            switch (resp['status']) {
              case 1:
                $('div#result').removeClass('failed').addClass('success').text('Password changed to ' + $('input[name="pass1"]').val()).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);

                tmp_pass = $('input[name="pass1"]').val();

                break;
              case 0:
              default:
                $('div#result').removeClass('success').addClass('failed').text('Wrong passwords for changing').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
                break;
            }

          });

        } else {
          $('div#result').removeClass('success').addClass('failed').text('Wrong passwords for changing').fadeIn(2000).fadeOut(2000);
        }


        break;
    }

    $('form input[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled');


  });

});
```

```css
form {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
form input,
form button {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 7px;
}
div#result {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  ;
}
.success {
  background: green;
}
.failed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5">
  <input type="password" name="cPass">
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="pass1">
  <br>
  <input type="password" name="pass2">
  <br>
  <input type='button' value='Change Password'>
</form>

<div id="result" style="display : none;"></div>
```

Comment: увы с jq совсем не знаком

Comment: @ddeadlink, если нужна детальная помощь - то обращайтесь на почту.